# Identifying two 6 pin SMD packages

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I need some help identifying these 2 SMD parts. One says `.3Ft` and the other says `.1Ft`. They each have 6 pins.

They are found on a DCC decoder for model trains.

[image]

Comment: Could be absolutely anything. What's a DCC decoder? BTW, the "." denotes pin 1 and has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: Note that the dot isn't related to marking code, is simply the Pin 1 mark, to show the chip orientation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes googling SOT23 and the marking works!
This time it got close enough to identify the package as a SOT363.

Apparently they are simply transistors - the [BC857](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC857BS.pdf) and [BC847](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC847BS.pdf). See the section "Marking" on page 2 of each datasheet.

Answer (score 12):

The first one is a dual PNP, [BC857BS](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC857BS.pdf) by NXP.

[image]

The second one is a dual NPN/PNP, [BC847BPN](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC847BPN.pdf), by NXP.

[image]